# Overriding method as varargs and Overridden method is normal method

Tags: java

```
public class DemoParent {
public void m1(int i) {
    System.out.println("parent");
}
}

public class DemoChild extends DemoParent{
public void m1(int... i) {
    System.out.println("child");
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    DemoParent p = new DemoChild();
    p.m1(10);

    DemoChild c = new DemoChild();
    c.m1(10);
}
}
```

Here I have two class DemoParent and DemoChild which extends DemoParent, in DemoParent i have general method m1(int i) but in DemoChild i have varargs method m1(int... i). When i am creating object of child class and calling m1 method,it's giving me parent class method output. See below the output.
o/p- parent
     parent

Can anyone explain me why parent class method is always calling from the Child class reference even if child has the same method?

but if we reverse the code i.e. parent class have varargs method and child has normal method then it will acts as an overloading instead of Overriding . So the output is
o/p - parent
      child

but in the above 1st scenario i didn't understand why always parent class method is calling from child reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not overriding. You're overloading.

`DemoChild` has two methods called `m1`, and it has to choose which of the methods to invoke, based on the fact that you pass a single `int` as a parameter.

The non-varargs method will always be matched before the varargs overload, because the language spec rules around method invocation say that it will be (to preserve backwards compatibility with pre-varargs code).